# Input scope for keyboard without suggestions in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 Universal app and would like to have a keyboard without suggestions and emoticons for the `TextBox`. It was the default keyboard in Windows Phone 8 Silverlight, but in Universal Apps suggestions are displayed if you don't specify `InputScope` (I believe it's defaults to `Default`).

I tried setting InputScope to `Default`, `Url`, and `Search` with no luck. Most of the values from Silverlight (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx) don't work either.

Desired keyboard (without suggestions, emoticons, and '.com' and '@' buttons):

[image: Default Keyboard]

How do I get such keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn suggestions off in a you can use

```
 IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following keyboard with the `CurrencyAmountAndSymbol` Input Scope. here you will have the `@` symbol. However, you can't simply avoid @ from the keyboard.

This will not have suggestions, emoticons, and .com

To avoid typing @ you can use KeyUp event.

```
<TextBox InputScope="CurrencyAmountAndSymbol"/>
```